# Object.keys.map does't return the original keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I'm getting an object from my database:
example:

```
{availability: null
bio: null
category: ""
createdAt: "2020-10-13T13:47:29.495Z"
email: "oznerol@prova.com"
firstName: "Lorenzo"
id: 37
image: null
job: null
lastName: "Del Rosario"
location: ""
password: "$2b$10$J6m71nc8gBXTvEENMwBjt.azNitCsna3LsxaDIUg.B0ztiTm5xFea"
phone: ""
skills: null
updatedAt: "2020-10-13T13:47:29.495Z"
website: ""}
```

I'm trying to map through this object to change all the `null` values to `''`.

This is my code:

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState()

useEffect( ()=>{
    
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const a = await getUserData(userId);//this retuns the object
    const cleanUserData = Object.entries(a).map(([key, value]) =>
      value === null || undefined ? value = '' : value
    )
    setUserData(cleanUserData);
  };
  fetchData();
},[])
```

but in this way i change my values but i loose my keys and the result is an object like this:

```
{0:37
1:"oznerol@prova.com"
2:"$2b$10$J6m71nc8gBXTvEENMwBjt.azNitCsna3LsxaDIUg.B0ztiTm5xFea"
3:"Lorenzo"
4:"Del Rosario"
5:""
6:""
7:""
8:""
9:""
10:""
11:""
12
...}
```

Comment: BTW, your api has a major security flaw: the response **should not** include the password.

Comment: Yes, that will be my next step, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `Object.entries` and `Object.keys` return an array, so when you use `map` on that the result will be an array. Use `reduce` instead to create the new object like so:

```
const cleanUserData = Object.entries(a).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  acc[key] = value == null ? '' : value;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

**Note:** Your original test `value === null || undefined` is not correct because that's not how you test against two possible values, it should be `value === null || value === undefined`. Also the test `value == null` (using the double-equal `==`) is sufficient as `undefined == null` in javascript.

**Demo:**

```js
const a = {availability: null, bio: null, category: "", createdAt: "2020-10-13T13:47:29.495Z", email: "oznerol@prova.com", firstName: "Lorenzo", id: 37, image: null, job: null, lastName: "Del Rosario", location: "", password: "$2b$10$J6m71nc8gBXTvEENMwBjt.azNitCsna3LsxaDIUg.B0ztiTm5xFea", phone: "", skills: null, updatedAt: "2020-10-13T13:47:29.495Z", website: ""};

const cleanUserData = Object.entries(a).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  acc[key] = value == null ? '' : value;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(cleanUserData);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now!
I just made a slight change and made it like this:
`const a = await getUserData(userId);
  const cleanUserData = Object.entries(a).reduce(  (accumulator, [key, value]) => {
    return {...accumulator, [key] : (value == null ? '' : value)}
  }, {})
  setUserData(cleanUserData)
}`

I need to dig more on the logic of these high order functions because i don't really know how to use them in a proficent way.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to use e.g. `Object.fromEntries` to recreate the main object after mapping.

```js
const o = {availability: null, bio: null, category: '', createdAt: "2020-10-13T13:47:29.495Z", email: "oznerol@prova.com", firstName: "Lorenzo", id: 37, image: null, job: null, lastName: "Del Rosario", location: "", password: "$2b$10$J6m71nc8gBXTvEENMwBjt.azNitCsna3LsxaDIUg.B0ztiTm5xFea", phone: '', skills: null, updatedAt: "2020-10-13T13:47:29.495Z", website: "",};

const res = Object.fromEntries(
   Object.entries(o).map(([key, val]) => [key, val ?? '']),
);

console.log(res);
// then set the state -> setUserData(res);
```

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea that this method existed, looks like it's made exactly for my needs!

Answer (score 2):

Please check this solution

```
 Object.keys(x).reduce((acc, key)=> {
    acc[key] = x[key] === null ? '' : x[key];
    return acc;
    }, {})
```

P.S.

> The Object.entries() method returns an array of a given object's own
> enumerable string-keyed property [key, value] pairs.

That's why you receive an index instead of the real key

Comment: What about the values `false` and `0`? This will replace all falsy values including `false` and `0`. OP wants to replace only `null` and `undefined`

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but shouldn't it be `x[key] === null ? '' : x[key]` and not the other way around? Your code will keep `null`s but replace every other value with `''`

Answer (score 1):

Simple, you can use map reduce functions to get your results.

```js
const obj = {
  "availability": null,
  "bio": null,
  "category": "",
  "createdAt": "2020-10-13T13:47:29.495Z",
  "email": "oznerol@prova.com",
  "firstName": "Lorenzo",
  "id": 37,
  "image": null,
  "job": null,
  "lastName": "Del Rosario",
  "location": "",
  "password": "$2b$10$J6m71nc8gBXTvEENMwBjt.azNitCsna3LsxaDIUg.B0ztiTm5xFea",
  "phone": "",
  "skills": null,
  "updatedAt": "2020-10-13T13:47:29.495Z",
  "website": ""
}

const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = (obj[curr] === null || obj[curr] === undefined)  ? '' : obj[curr]
    return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This will replace all falsy values including `false` and `0`. OP wants to replace only `null` and `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution by copying the object:

```js
const data ={
  availability: null,
  bio: null,
  category: "",
  createdAt: "2020-10-13T13:47:29.495Z",
  email: "oznerol@prova.com",
  firstName: "Lorenzo",
  id: 37,
  image: null,
  job: null,
  lastName: "Del Rosario",
  location: "",
  password: "$2b$10$J6m71nc8gBXTvEENMwBjt.azNitCsna3LsxaDIUg.B0ztiTm5xFea",
  phone: "",
  skills: null,
  updatedAt: "2020-10-13T13:47:29.495Z",
  website: ""
}; 


let cleanUserData = (data) => {
    const cleanData = {};
    Object.keys(data).forEach((key) =>
      cleanData[key] = data[key] === null ? '' : data[key]
    )
    return cleanData;
  };

console.log(cleanUserData(data));
```